# Index numbers for row-wise duplicate entries using numpy/pandas in python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array/pandas data frame

```
[[0 0 0 1],
 [1 0 0 1],
 [0 0 0 1],
 [1 0 0 1],
 [0 0 0 1],
 [0 0 1 0],
 [0 0 1 0]]
```

I need index number of row duplicates for this array. The results should be something like (0,2,4), (1,3), (5,6).

So far I have a work around, like I am running loops, one with unique values of the array rows against the actual array rows. That gives me results but not in the fashion I would want them to be.
This is the code I have made which gives me pairs but for a large array, this is very messy.

```
for i, row in enumerate(array):
    for j, row1 in enumerate(unique(array)):
        if tuple(row)==tuple(row1):
            pair.append(tuple([j,i]))
```

my results looks like this:

```
 [(0, 276),(1, 2931),(2, 3891),(3, 2165),(4, 1822),(5, 1241),
 (5, 2635),(5, 2644),(5, 2862),(5, 3296)]
```

My array is very big, so this way I am manually choosing tuples based on the first value as the indicator for duplicates, then I choose the actual row number which is a duplicate. for Ex. - tuples having 5 as their first value mean row 1241 is duplicated at 2635, 2644, 2862 and 3296.

Can anyone suggest me a better way to work on this problem.
I have looked around here but nothing concrete I could get.

Answer (score 0):

`a` being your array, a efficient way to do that is to consider each row like bytes, to accelerate row comparisons:

```
v=np.array(a)   
rows=v.view(dtype=np.void(v.strides[0]))
```

As exemple :

```
In [4]: a,b=randint(0,1,(2,10000))

In [5]: %timeit tuple(a)==tuple(b)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.12 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit str(a)==str(b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 901 µs per loop

In [7]: %timeit typ=np.void(a.strides[0]);a.view(typ)==b.view(typ)
1000 loops, best of 3: 227 µs per loop
```

`rows` is now :

```
array([[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]],
       [[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]],
       [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]],
       [[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]],
       [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]],
       [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]],
       [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]], 
      dtype='|V16')
```

Then you can sort them, locating the base member with the `return_inverse` parameter of `np.unique`  :

```
uniq,inverse=np.unique(rows,return_inverse=True)
```

And pretty print the results :

```
In [28]: [(a[i] , list((inverse==i).nonzero()[0])) for i in range(uniq.size)]
Out[28]: [([0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 4]), ([1, 0, 0, 1], [5, 6]), ([0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 3])]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert arrays to strings and simply find the indices of unique strings in the original array.

Let's use your array:

```
a = [[0, 0, 0, 1],
     [1, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 1],
     [1, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0]]


for unique in np.unique([str(el) for el in a]):
    print np.where(np.array([str(el) for el in a]) == str(unique))[0]
```

This would output:

```
[0 2 4]
[5 6]
[1 3]
```

As you wanted

Comment: this is good but is slow like my original code. thanks for the reply though, will try other solutions

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) aims to enrich numpy with functionality of this kind, and using it, your problem can be written as a simple and readable one-liner:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
idx_groups = npi.group_by(array).split(np.arange(len(array)))
```

Note that chances are, these indices are not actually the end result you are after, but are needed for a subsequent calculation; numpy_indexed has a lot of functionality for those type of common situations as well; so perhaps if you give some more context to your question, a more refined solution could be given too.

Comment: thanks for this, will try the package functionality to see how it helps.